# Finding the Maclaurin series of a function $f(x)=\ln\frac{2+x}{3-x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Finding the Maclaurin series of a function:
$$f(x)=\ln\frac{2+x}{3-x}$$
I tried to solve this task like this:
\begin{align}\ln\frac{2+x}{3-x}&=\ln(2+x)-\ln(3-x)\\&=\ln\left(2\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\ln\left(3\left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)\\&=\ln 2+\ln\left(\frac{x}{2}+1\right)-\ln3-\ln\left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right)\\&=\ln\frac{2}{3}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{2^kk}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}(-1)^k\frac{x^k}{3^kk}\\&=\ln\frac{2}{3}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}\left(\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^k}+\frac{1}{3^k}\right)\end{align}
but at some point I made an mistake and I don't really understand what is wrong, so any tips on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong there. That's the correct series.